# Calculate the sum of all even numbers between n and m

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate numbers between `n` and `m`, but something goes wrong and I don't know what..

```js
function even(){
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  var m = document.getElementById("m").value;
  var s = 0 ;
  if(n<m){
    i = n;
    while(i<=n){
      n*(n+2)/4;
      i++;
      alert(n.value)
    }
  }else if(n>m);{
    i=m;
    S=n*(n+2)/4;
    i++
    alert(m.value)
  }   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n" > </br><br>
<input type="text" id="m" > </br><br>
<button onclick="even()">Click me !</button>
```

Comment: What's that something that goes wrong?

Comment: Comparing strings and calculating with strings can lead unexpected results.

Comment: I bet there's a formula to do this without using a loop.

Comment: First, to retrieve even number, I think it's a better way to do : n % 2

Comment: old gauss comes in handy.

Comment: You get the value using `var n = document.getElementById("n").value;` and you display it with `alert(n.value)` The .value is already used and is undefined in the `alert()`

Comment: i just copy the pseudocode i have in my notebook .. i get undefined alert .. even when i use n%2==0;. i have those :document.getElementByid("n") couse i got some textboxes . how i shoud write it to alert (result)?

Comment: `else if(n>m);` is wrong. Remove the `;` otherwise it's like writting `else if(n>m) { ; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are specifically told to use a loop you should use the formula for sum of arithmetic progression.

```js
function even() {
  let n1 = Number(document.getElementById("n").value);
  let n2 = Number(document.getElementById("m").value);
  if (n1 > n2) [n1,n2] = [n2,n1];
  n1 = 2*Math.ceil(n1/2);
  n2 = 2*Math.floor(n2/2);
  if (n1 > n2) return 0;
  return (n1 + n2) * ((n2 - n1) / 2 + 1) / 2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n" > <br><br>
<input type="text" id="m" > <br><br>
<button onclick="alert(even())">Click me !</button>
```

Even if you use a loop you should consider making number even first and then increment loop variable by 2 every time instead of checking parity on each iteration.

Comment: Good to see a proper approach here, using a formula instead of a "dumb" / "naive" loop.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to calculate the sum, however, in your while loop, you were not adding it to the sum and trying to alert `n.value` or `m.value` which will be `undefined` here as there is no `value` property.

You can define a logic for the same (AP) rather than looping

```js
function even(){
   // convert the values to numbers otherwise it will be strings
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
    
    if (n > m) [n, m] = [m, n]; // store smaller number in n
    n = (n%2 === 0) ? n: n+1; // find the first even number
    m = (m%2 === 0) ? m: m-1; // find the last even number
    
    var s = 0; // initialize sum to 0
    if(m >= n) {
      var numbers = (m-n)/2 + 1; // number of even numbers in the range
      /* Understanding the formula. It is a basic airthmetic series of n
       * numbers, with first number being a, last number being l
       * which is equal to (a + (n-1)d) where difference
       * being d. The sum will be n/2(a+l) => n/2(a + a + (n-1)d)
       * => n/2(2a + (n-1)d). With our d being 2, equation becomes
       * n/2(2a +(n-1)2) => n(a + n -1). */
      s = numbers*(n + numbers-1);
    }
    
    alert(s);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n" > </br><br>
    <input type="text" id="m" > </br><br>
    <button onclick="even()">Click me !</button>
```

Or you can update your code to following

```js
function even(){
   // convert the values to numbers otherwise it will be strings
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
    var s = 0 ;
    var i;
    // Iterate over the numbers and check if it is divisible by 2 if yes then add it to the sum and finally alert the sum
    if(n<m){
        i = n;
        while(i<=m){
            if(i%2 === 0) s += i;
            i++;
        }
        alert(s);
    }else if(n>m) {
        i=m;
        while(i<=n){
            if(i%2 === 0) s += i;
            i++;
        }
        alert(s);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n" > </br><br>
    <input type="text" id="m" > </br><br>
    <button onclick="even()">Click me !</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform calculations only for even numbers, you need to find the remainder of the division. The remainder of the division must be zero

```
let a = 2;
let b = 10;
for(let i = a; i <= b; i++){
  if (i%2 === 0){
    // do something here even numbers
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (n < m) {
    for (let i = n; i <= m; i++) {
        if (i%2 === 0)
            s += i;
    }

} else {
    for (let i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i%2 === 0)
            s += i;
    }
}
```

The line `if (s%2 === 0)` is key to this because it will only add the numbers in the range which have a 0 remainder when divided by 2 (are even). 
I've also converted the while loops you had into for loops because they are cleaner and easier to read.

You could also attempt to use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to quickly set-up lower and upper variables if you want to eliminate the need for the outer if-else statements.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Answer has been updated to be more explanatory.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. This way, the answer is also helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

I have taken the numbers as 10 and 3 and I am not considering both the numbers in loop because you have asked for sum of even numbers between these two.I have taken sum as 0.I have found the highest and lowest number using Ternary operator.using for loop i have found the Even integers and added them.

```
        var x=10;
        var y=3;
        var higher=x>y?x:y;
        var lower=x>y?y:x;
        var sum=0;
        for(var i=lower+1;i<higher;i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
    console.log("sum is"+sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: It's ok like this . but i have 2 textboxes where i insert the value of the numbers . i will keep in mind this as well . ty

Comment: @shamsherKhan Oh I ___understand___ your answer. I just think it needs to be improved.

Comment: Code snippet isn't made for understanding code. It's a way for viewers to easily check your code.

Comment: @Avram Adrian This is basic logic required for adding even numbers.Replace x,y with your 2 input values and kindly keep validation  that entered value must be integer otherwise it wont run

Comment: @shamsherKhan, it was a little pretentious saying to the person that they don't understand while they have js gold badge

Comment: @Vega what you want me to do now ? apologize?

Comment: No, @shamsherKhan. I don't want an apology, but please keep in mind that not everyone that requests that you improve the answer, does so because they don't _understand_ it. Some people prefer seeing a well written answer over something that only just "works", but isn't explained.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you so much for your suggestion.will try to explain my answer from next time onwards.